# Trigger the event after making the HTML object in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want an event to be triggered after the creation of the corresponding HTML object (`href` in my case).

I've written this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#stats-link', function(e) {
        console.log('TRIGGERED'); // nothing is logged
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('stats.php', {'email': $('#email').val()}, function() {
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        });
    });

    $('#submit_button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
        $('#info').html('<p class="desc"><a href="stats.php" id="stats-link">bla bla bla</a></p>');
        ...
    });
});
```

So, I make a `href` object identified by `stats-link` in the `#submit_button` function, then I want him to be triggered in the corresponding function (i.e., `$('body').on(...)`, but it doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If #submit_button is a submit button, you need to cancel that too: `$('#submit_button').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();` - laso you now ajax posts to stats.php then change the location to the same file. That does not seem right

Comment: Added. Nothing changes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you missed this line:

```
$('#stats-link').trigger('click');
```

This will trigger the click event. The code you shared only binds the event. You need to trigger it.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#stats-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('clicked')
        $.post('stats.php', {
            'email': $('#email').val()
        }, function () {
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        });
    });

    $('#submit_button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#info').html('<p class="desc"><a href="stats.php" id="stats-link">bla bla bla</a></p>');
        $('#stats-link').trigger('click'); //This is where you trigger the click.
    });
});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/artaq4xj/

Comment: Where do I need to put that?

Comment: You need to put it after you append that href object or anchor link.After this line: $('#info').html('<p class="desc"><a href="stats.php" id="stats-link">bla bla bla</a></p>');

Comment: @f_ficarola Check the demo, let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Well, not really. In your code when you click on `SFDSF` button/link, the `$('body').on('click', '#stats-link', function (e) {...});` is triggered. I want that function to be triggered after only I click on the link `bla bla bla`.

Comment: So where is the problem? Remove the trigger line and it should work on your click too.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but that's equal to my code, right? I cannot understand why it does not work on my web page.

Comment: Yeah. Can you share your website link where you have this code?

Comment: God, a missed double quotes in my html code... That works now, argh! Anyway, thank you again for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

What is `e`?  Are you sure the click event isn't actually working, but just giving you a script error and bailing out before it does anything?  Your callback function does not define the passed in `event` parameter `e`.

```
$('body').on('click', '#stats-link', function() { // <-- No e parameter supplied.
        e.preventDefault();  // <---- What is e?
        ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your correction... I've forgotten the `e` in the function, but that wasn't the problem, the situation is still the same. I've tried to put `console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAA");`, but the console doesn't print anything and I don't have any error.

Answer (score 1):

Your preventDefault() parameter is lacked :

```
$('body').on('click', '#stats-link', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('stats.php', {'email': $('#email').val()}, function() {
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I've already updated my post after the Lochemage's answer. I forgot the write `e`, but the situation does not change.